# Reescribir la siguiente función usando el operador ? y otra usando el operador II

Tags: javascript

Tengo que reemplazar este código de 2 maneras y lo he conseguido de una de ellas

```
function checkAge(age) {
  if (age > 18) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return confirm('Did parents allow you?');
  }
}
```

Con `?`(operador ternario) he conseguido hacerlo poniendo esto

```
function checkAge(age) {
    mayor = (age >= 18) ? true : confirm('Did parents allow you?');
    return mayor;
}
```

Pero me faltaría usando el operador II, tengo entendido que es para decir "o esto o lo otro" pero no veo la manera de ponerlo en este ejemplo.

Comment: Exactamente es lo que me pregunto yo, no hay explicación alguna en el ejercicio...

Answer (score 1):

Algo como:

```
function checkAge(age) {
  return age > 18 || confirm('Did parents allow you?');
}
```

El operador `||` a veces se utiliza para ejecutar codigo por defecto, como por ejemplo cuando recibes un argumento que podria no estar definido:

```
function doSomething(arg) {
  const variable = arg || 10;
}
```

Si `arg` se puede interpretar como `true` (truthy) entonces el resultado de la expresión es `arg`, de lo contrario es `10`. Esta evaluación se conoce como "short-circuit" (corto circuito)

Te recomiendo leer el siguiente articulo de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos) donde se explica con mas detalle.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien ya hay una muy buena respuesta al respecto, a lo que pienso que se refería el ejercicio era a que tu te dieras cuenta de la diferencia entre usar:

- shorthand conditionals
- logic or operator

Y también que te dieras cuenta que en esos casos, en ambos se puede usar ya sea `shorthand conditionals` o `logic or operator`, donde podemos escribir tus dos funciones tanto con `shorthand conditionals` como con el `logic or operator` (`||`), asi que vamos a mirar **los primeros dos casos de la primera función**, actualmente **originalmente** se ve asi:

```
function checkAge(age) {
  if (age > 18) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return confirm('Did parents allow you?');
  }
}
```

Usando `shorthand conditionals`:

```js
function checkAge(age){
   return age > 18 ? true : confirm('Did parents allow you?');
}

console.log(checkAge(18));
```

Usando `logic or operator`:

```js
function checkAge(age){
   return age > 18 || confirm('Did parents allow you?');
}

console.log(checkAge(18));
```

Naturalmente es exactamente el mismo resultado, solo que uno de nuestros caminos es un poco mas corto que el otro, si bien puede ser indistinguible para alguien que esta comenzando el decidir cual de los dos usar y la diferencia entre ellos, si que hay una diferencia, pero primero vamos a establecer similitudes:

**Similitudes**

- El resultado de ambos depende de condicionales.
- Ambos se usan para acortar asignaciones o resultados de operaciones.
- Ambos pueden ser usados para obtener valores logicos (booleanos) apartir de una expresión condicional.

**Diferencias**

- La sintaxis que engloba el orden de las condiciones difiere, en **shorthand conditionals** no es necesario usar paréntesis para definir las condiciones, usando **logical expressions** dependiendo de como queremos agrupar las condiciones debemos usar paréntesis.
- En `shorthand conditionals` si defines una condición (`?`), obligatoriamente debes cerrarla con su contrario (`:`), el resultado será uno de aquellos valores que hayamos establecido, mientras que usando **logical expressions** no es necesario definir un simbolo de cierre del condicional. En este caso el operador `||` actuaria como doble condicional, dándonos ya sea un valor u otro.
- Dependiendo de ciertas condiciones, un `shorthand conditional` puede ser mas conveniente que `logical expressions`, por ejemplo cuando queremos controlar no una, si no varias condicionales para asignar el valor de una variable (se puede hacer), mientras que `logical expressions` viene mejor para condiciones muy cortas o que solo vayan a disponer de ya sea un valor u otro.